# Failed to resolve component: router-link and router-view

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-router

`router-view` and `router-link` components cannot be resolved in my app
I don't know what the problem is

attached the app code
it's a home page app with something like a `navbar` to route to the vue components like `states`

App\resources\js\router.js

```
import States from './components/States.vue'
import Cities from './components/Cities.vue'
import Areas from './components/Areas.vue'
import Addresses from './components/Addresses.vue'

const router =createRouter({
    history:createWebHistory,
    routes :[
        {
            name:'states',
            path:'/states',
            Commponent: States
        },
        {
            name:'cities',
            path:'/cities',
            Commponent: Cities
        },
        {
            name:'areas',
            path:'/areas',
            Commponent: Areas
        },
        {
            name:'addresses',
            path:'/addresses',
            Commponent: Addresses
        }
    ]
})

export default new VueRouter({
    router
});
```

App\resources\js\app.js

```
import App from './components/App.vue'
import router from './router'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import axios from 'axios'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(VueAxios,axios,router)
app.mount('#MyApp')
```

App\resources\js\components\App.vue

```
  <div class="container">
        <h2>welcome to vue</h2>
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <router-link to="/states">States</router-link>
            <router-link to="/cities">Cities</router-link>
            <router-link to="/areas">Areas</router-link>
            <router-link to="/addresses">Addresses</router-link>
        </div>.
        <router-view />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

C:\Users\Kareem\App\resources\js\components\States.vue

```
  <h3>welcome to states component</h3>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

Answer (score 7):

Try like this for Vue3:

```
import { createApp } from "vue";

createApp(App)
  .use(VueAxios, axios)
  .use(router)
  .mount('#MyApp')
```

Comment: vue components disappeared from the output when i tried this

Comment: @kareem hey mate,  instead `export default new VueRouter({ router});` try with `export default router`